# Add something to Facebook stream via URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, dialog, stream

I have a [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/73032) (read: my Javascript on someone else's site) that allows users to share their IMDb votes with their Facebook friends.  I just generate a URL for a Facebook share page with all of the custom information needed for the specific situation, something like "So and so gave the film Forrest Gump a rating of 9/10 on IMDb" with links to a thumbnail and the movie page itself, and allow the user to add their their thoughts on the movie itself.

[script with Facebook share dialog http://s3.amazonaws.com/uso_ss/10985/large.png?1284850755](http://s3.amazonaws.com/uso_ss/10985/large.png?1284850755)

Until recently, I accomplished this by passing all of my parameters to http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php.  Yesterday this broke, and it appears that Facebook is deprecating this sharing method in favor of using their [Dialog code](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/). (All of the official FB docs now refer to prompt_feed.php as the "old" way of sharing.)

I found a temporary workaround [here](http://crazydavinci.net/2011/06/facebook-prompt-feed-via-twitter-without-via/) that just adds a display=touch variable to the prompt_feed query string.  [This URL](http://on.fb.me/iuEtiW) is working for the time being (go ahead and click it!), but I fear that it's a loophole that Facebook will close as soon as they realize it's still available, and I'll be stuck without a way to post stuff to FB.

The current methods of posting to Facebook seem to be 1) using the [Dialog URL](http://on.fb.me/jCtVTy) mentioned above and 2) via Javascript using [FB.ui](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/)  Both of these methods appear to require a Facebook App ID, and when I registered a new FB app for this purpose and tried to use it to create a http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed request, I got an error because my app doesn't "own" the IMDb page that it's linking to.  Any ideas about how to accomplish my purposes going forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to "own" the imdb page you just need to set the canvas url to the imdb domain.

Comment: Rufinus, that worked perfectly!  I'm now using the [Dialog url](http://on.fb.me/jIFtOS) with my Facebook App in my [userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/73032).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use this url:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.your-url-to-share.com
```

Just modify or change the `http://www.your-url-to-share.com` part in the above URL with url of the webpage or article that you want to share on the facebook feeds.

Comment: I could potentially use that sharer url to link to an IMDb page, but not share the vote information like I'm currently doing.  IMDb already has this functionality built in.  This is not a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the sharer.php and want text plus a link add the &t={text} to the url.  For example:
    http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.your-url-to-share.com&t=text-to-share